# Can we make mobile application using ARCORE on Xamarin or Ionic?

Tags: xamarin, ionic-framework, cross-platform, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to make an application on Augmented Reality. I was intending to use simple Android Studio, but I thought it would be much better if I use Xamarin/Ionic, because it is cross-platform.

Comment: first hit from Google - https://blog.xamarin.com/augmented-reality-xamarin-android-arcore/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check out these implementations for xamarin forms
https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-arcore-sample

Xamarin University Guest Lecture - Michael Zaletel - ARKit and ARCore
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpp4E4T9Z9c

Comment: kindly consider adding more information from the links relevant to the answer, its helpful in case the link is removed