# Is ARCore compatible with Ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, augmented-reality, arcore, capacitor

I want to create an AR app and read on the internet that ARCore is one of the things to work with. I previously tried basic app devolpment with Ionic and was pretty satisfied with it.

Therefore I was wondering if it is possible to integrate ARCore into an Ionic app (e.g. in an AR-tab)?

I found [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467510/can-we-make-mobile-application-using-arcore-on-xamarin-or-ionic) but it is just considering Xamarin and not Ionic...

I also found that it should be possible to [integrate ARCore into Android](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart) (Java/Kotlin - which both could be used with Capacitor). But I am not really sure how (new to this topic) - can the ARCore elements just be copy and pasted to the desired tab inside my Ionic project?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Wikitude SDK for AR App .. its support ionic follow this link below :
**https://www.wikitude.com/download-wikitude-sdk-for-cordova/**